# Is using "wish" like this exclusive to India? “Did you wish her?”

Tags: word-usage, subcontinental-english

I'm talking about [wish](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wish) the verb in the following sense only:

> 1.1 [WITH TWO OBJECTS] Express a hope that (someone) enjoys (happiness or success):
>
> *they wish her every success*

As we can see, Oxford dictates that wish must have two objects when used in this sense.

In India, it's *extremely* common to drop the second object when it's understood.

For example:

> It's her birthday today. Did you wish her?

It's highly unlikely in India that anyone would say “Did you wish her a happy birthday?”

In the above example, at least the context was introduced in the previous sentence, but this usage is also possible without mentioning the context when it is known by the people involved. For instance, on Mother's Day, a brother could ask his sister: “Did you wish Mom?” It's understood that he's talking about Mother's Day.

Also, it's common to introduce the context in the same sentence without using  a second object. As in:

> Ever since we broke up she doesn't even wish me on birthdays.

My questions:

- Do native speakers use “wish” like this?
- If they don't, does this sound right to them?
- Is it a feature of Indian English; or downright wrong?
- (EDIT:) How would a native speaker phrase these example sentences?

Comment: I can only speak from personal experience, so I won't post it as an answer. I had never heard this use of _wish_ before I came into contact with speakers of InE. Once I did, I readily understood the meaning, and I have heard many speakers of InE use the verb like this. I would consider it indeed a standard InE usage of the verb _wish_.

Comment: @oerkelens: Good to hear that you don't think it's wrong. I actually meant to ask this question earlier, when I saw a post in which an Indian user had used wish like this and curiousdanii pointed out it's wrong. I didn't even realize natives don't use it like this before then.

Comment: I think it's a matter of opinion whether this usage (non-standard to Anglophones at large) is "wrong", since there's no authoritative body endorsing *any* "non-standard" usages that happen to be more common among Indian English speakers than anywhere else.

Comment: It is just ungrammatical; whether and what can be understood just depends on the listener. *Did you wish her?*  (wish what?) or might  even sounds like, *Did you desire her?*.

Comment: @Josh61: It doesn't sound good to me either, but [Cambridge Dictionaries acknowledge the usage](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/wish) **Indian English:** to welcome someone with particular words or a particular action: *He wishes me every morning.* Perhaps because there's a common Hindi word that can be used this way, and/or conflation with ***to greet***.

Comment: @Josh61: the fact that understanding depends on the listener doesn't make it ungrammatical. That is like saying "do you have a rubber?" or "do you want a fag?" are non-semantic because the meaning differs greatly between AmE and BrE speakers. I agree that (most, if not all) native speakers of AmE and BrE would at least frown upon this usage of _wish_, but whose language is it, anyway?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - what would you say to a student of  yours who uses that sentence?

Comment: @Josh61: I'd repeat what I said above - it's non-standard to *mainstream* native Anglophones. My experience of Indians who have settled in the UK is that the vast majority of them do *not* wish to "accidentally" identify themselves as speakers of *Indian* English (which usually isn't their *native* language anyway). And the *children* of such émigrés (who usually *are* native Anglophones) are often even more concerned about such matters than their parents. They just want to sound like everyone else in their new homeland.

Comment: 1) Do native speakers use wish like this? AmE, BrE, AusE, etc don't use this. 
2) If they don't, does this sound right to them? They also don't understand it.
3) Is it a feature of Indian English; or downright wrong? Sort of both. It is 'wrong' in those varieties I listed. It must not be wrong in IndE.

Comment: @Mitch: Thanks. Mind answering my fourth q: How would a native speaker put it?

Comment: Nice question, until I joined EL&U I would have said it made no sense, but I see this usage time and time again. Once you know, then there isn't any real problem, and I'm sure that the context  makes the meaning quite clear. (But I don't see myself adopting this usage)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: And I'm at a loss how else to say it :(

Comment: As for your example sentences, "Did you wish her happy birthday" does the trick (it's implied that it's her birthday, so you save a sentence). "Since we broke up she doesn't even wish me happy birthday." Again, she wouldn't be expected to do that except on birthdays, so you don;t need to repeat that.

Comment: I don't see why this question has a close vote.  I think monotransitive *wish* is a well known feature of Indian English.  It's described in *Indian and British English: A Handbook of Usage and Pronunciation* (2004, p.197) and *Contemporary Indian English: Variation and Change* (2009, p.106), for example.  It's not a feature of AmE or BrE (for example), and an answer can plainly say so and answer the rest of the OP's questions.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction 4) How would a native speaker put it? Like you said "Did you wish her a happy birthday?" In AmE/BrE you must say what it is you wished if you are directing the wish at somebody (like the rule says , 2 objects, the person and the wish itself). The intransitive 'wish' goes with 'for' (when there's just you wishing) "I wished _for_ three more wishes."

Comment: Here's a recent InEng question using "wish" [How to wish a colleague going on maternity leave?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246461/how-to-wish-a-colleague-going-on-maternity-leave/246463#246463)

Comment: New expression learnt! I guess I’m not that frequently exposed to Indian English—I had never heard this usage before in my life. I doubt I would have understood what was meant without the explanation.

Comment: I have a hunch that the InEng usage is derived from the polite salutation: *Best wishes*, i.e. the writer is politely saying "I hope everything goes well for you", and  the phrase "send her/him my best wishes".In those cases two objects are not needed.*Wishes* (noun) in Italian is *auguri*, and it's very common to just say to one another [**Auguri!**](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/auguri) when it is Xmas or the New Year. [**Tanti auguri**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/tanti-auguri-) is literally "many wishes" which Italians say to each other on birthdays.

Comment: There are four downvotes, which is a huge shame. I'd like to hear theories as to how this InEng usage came about, how old it is, and whether InEng speakers use this form of greeting to other native (BrEng and AmEng) and non-native speakers. Is this more common among British Indians/Asians or N.American Indian English speakers? Does this practice continue to the next generation or are their children "taught" out of it at school?

Comment: It seems we need a separate site for Indian English Language and Usage, since it's clearly a different animal than what we AmE and BrE speakers consider "standard", " common", "acceptable", or whatever. It differs not only in terminology, but in syntax and grammar. I consider myself quite conversant in the subtleties of English usage as practiced in North America, but I can see that much of this hard-earned knowledge is of no use when confronted with "normal" Indian English expressions such as "Did you wish her?".   Of course, it is fascinating to discover how Indians use the language

Comment: _Do native speakers use wish like this?_ Whom do you mean by "native speakers"?  Do you mean non-Indian-born English speakers? Or are you looking for native speakers of, say, American, Canadian, British, or Australian English?

Comment: EDIT: I meant "vote to close" votes. British English, Australian Eng, N.Zealand Eng, Irish Eng, N.American Eng, Canadian Eng, Malaysian Eng, Singapore Eng ...(and those are the ones I've only heard about) So many Englishes :) Lots of dialects to get to grips with!

Comment: My fiancée's family is Sri Lankan with English as their primary language, and they use 'wish' like this all the time. As another example, her step-father (a native-born Australian) said "people will want to wish you after your wedding". They have always insisted that it is a perfectly normal way of using the word, despite my confusion at never having heard anyone else do it. This question helped me finally clarify that it's not some bizarre family-specific usage!

Comment: @Mark You're welcome :) It's interesting that a native-born Australian uses it this way.

Comment: @TusharRaj I meant to mention (but missed the chance to edit) that he has been married to his Sri Lankan wife for a while and has lived there for a short time, so obviously has heard it in that context enough to pick up the meaning and adopt it into his vocab. It still sounds strange to me, so I don't think I'll be doing it myself just yet! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a hunch that the InEng (IE/IndE) usage is derived from the polite valediction, *[Best wishes](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/best-wishes)*, i.e. “I hope everything goes well for you”, and the phrase “send her/him my best wishes”. In both expressions two objects are not required, it is understood that the speaker is saying ‘I would like to send you the best of luck today.’

The InEng  usage of ‘wishes’(noun) sounds almost Italian to my ears.  In Italian the expression is *auguri*, and it's very common to just say to one another *Auguri!* when it is Christmas or the New Year. *[Tanti auguri](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/tanti-auguri-)* is literally ‘many wishes’ which Italians say to each other on birthdays, it is also used to say ‘congratulations’ and ‘good luck’.

But do BrEng speakers use this form? No, not really. Before joining El&U two years ago, I had never heard this form of exchange before; e.g. “Did you wish mum?” In none of the English coursebooks or grammar books I have bought over the years, have I come across this usage, so my guess would be that it is currently considered non-standard English. But whether native speakers would understand it, is a different question, and I'd say ‘absolutely!’
In "**I wish my colleague**", there's nothing to decypher. Context will tell us if, for example, the colleague is retiring or on maternity leave.

The form  has also entered the dictionary. In Cambridge Dictionaries Online

> **[wish](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/wish)** verb (GREET)
>
> [Transitive] Indian English to welcome someone with particular words or a particular action:
>   *He wishes me every morning.*

And its usage has been recorded by linguists and experts

> [Register Variation in Indian English](https://books.google.it/books?id=RB04Ay545rwC&pg=PT89&lpg=PT89&dq=%22Indian%20english%22%20usage%20wish&source=bl&ots=CNWVK1ytt2&sig=GW7csJCS4rZn1lUCBwBWbAOqZxY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VbteVc2cGcKuU4OYgKAP&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22Indian%20english%22%20usage%20wish&f=false)
>   <sup>By Chandrika Balasubramanian</sup>
>
> Indeed, Nihilani *et al* identify 1000 items (many lexical) in their lexicon of usage which they claim are “are used in a distinctive manner by large numbers of educated Indian speakers of English”
>
> **Wish**: “IVE (Indian Vernacular English) speakers often use this verb where a BS speaker would say ‘greet’. In BS (British Standard), what is wished must be expressed...”
>
> - *He wished me when we met this morning.*
> - *He's stopped wishing me*

---

How might a native speaker say the following sentence in British English?

> Ever since we broke up she doesn't even wish me on birthdays.

- Since we've broken up, she doesn't even call me on my birthday
- She never calls. She doesn't even wish me ‘Happy Birthday’ since we split up

Comment: Thanks for answering comprehensively. Since you asked, we're not taught 'Indian English' in our schools. We study BrE, and we pick some things up from around us; some of which are AmE, and some I guess would be InE. This usage of "wish" is so ubiquitous here that I'll have a hard time trying to phrase it any other way, not least because all other options sound a bit clunky to me. Someone in the comments said that this usage derives from translating a Hindi word. For the life of me, I can't guess what word he's talking about. And so, even I'm curious how exactly did this usage came to be.

Comment: I believe FumbleFingers was making a supposition, asking aloud whether  "wish" is monotransitive in Hindi. I understand fully that English is taught in India but I was only wondering if British-born Asians (Or American born) still adopt this usage, or if they are "taught out of it" at English-speaking schools.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock  But that's using "wish" to mean "desire", and to express frustration and irritation. We all know that "wish" has more than one meaning. My post is focussed on the greeting form. See the OP definition which is at the top of his question.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: The `wish` usage I'm talking about is rarely phrased that way. I've included examples of common ways it is said in my post. Would you still be confused about the meaning of `wish` in those cases? Or is it easy to deduce (albeit a little odd-sounding)?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: In Hindi, wish isn't even a verb. What we normally say can be translated as: "I gave her my best wishes (for Diwali/the new year/her birthday../)". I think this got abbreviated in InE to "I wished her".

Comment: I was simply being sarcastic. Yes, I could "deduce" (after you _explained it_—but on encountering such usage in situ, I would assume some words must have been left out. In the English I speak (AmE), there is no  "greeting form", so ending a sentence "I wish my colleague." can only invite conjecture as to WHAT I wish FOR or ABOUT my colleague.  "Wish" without a direct object literally does not compute in AmE (or, dare I say, does not exist). That's what I meant.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: I got that. What I'm saying is that your sarcasm is unfounded, because no one is likely to say `I wish my colleague`. They'd either say `I wished my colleague` or `I wish my colleague every Tuesday` or something. Would you still think that these sentences invite conjecture?

Comment: The more you explain @TusharRaj, the more your usage sounds like 'bless' (see my answer below).  An important difference is that usually 'blessing' is performed by religious officials whereas your use of wish, without a wished-for object, is clearly secular.

Comment: Absolutely. They are incomplete sentences in AmE.

Comment: Context, Brian, context. Why are you so bothered by this answer? If you really dislike this answer, and you must do because you keep coming back, then write a post yourself. I wrote an answer because I liked the question, I really like knowing about different and new expressions, dialects and slang. Slang can be incomprehensible to those who are unfamiliar with it. Once you are familiar, and you hear it being said around you, then you "learn" its meaning, and when it is used.

Comment: The same, I believe, is true for this InEng usage of "wish" in speech, and "I wish mom" is an elided sentence. I wish her *what*? In BrEng, and Ameng that is a valid criticism, but it's not a problem for InEng speakers. Elided sentences  are quite common in AmEng and BrEng speech too. Please, @BrianHitchcock,   drop the "sarcasm". I'm not stopping you from writing a better answer, in fact I look forward to seeing it.

Comment: I cannot answer whether that usage is _unique_ to Indian English. Indeed, I cannot even be certain that it is not used by native speakers of AmE. But I can tell that it looks ungrammatical to me as an AmE speaker, and have explained exactly why it does.

Answer (score 2):

*Do native speakers use wish like this?*
I haven't heard this use before (British English).  The way you are using wish - preferring not to specify the wished-for thing - sounds very like the way I would use the word 'bless' (which I don't use often).

*Does this sound right to them?*

It's unfamiliar but not off-puttingly so, and certainly thought-provoking!

This is how I would phrase the example sentences?

*It's her birthday today. Did you wish her?*  **It's her birthday today.  Did you wish her 'Happy birthday'?**

*Ever since we broke up she doesn't even wish me on birthdays.*  **Ever since we broke up she hasn't even remembered my birthday.**

Comment: Thanks for answering. Quick follow-up: In your first example, sounds to me like  _Did you do anything_ can range from a simple "wish" to a lavish surprise party. In your second example, a card may not be necessarily what I'm talking about. Most of the "wishing" nowadays happens over the phone or via social media. I'm trying to say she didn't bother to call/text, if only to say "Happy Birthday".

Comment: I see. Well, I'm not sure `she doesn't even wish me happy birthday` is grammatical. And I'm not sure if it should be `she doesn't even wish me happy birthdays` or `she doesn't even wish me a happy birthday`. They all sound alien to me.

Comment: @TusharRaj It's perhaps not grammatical, but "wish her 'Happy Birthday'" is common enough in American English. But "wish her" alone would not be understood.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a native, and I don't use this expression. It sounds quaint to me, but not downright wrong; I know educated Indians who use expressions that are substandard in British English, but Indian English is it own idiom. For example, indians will talk about a famous drunk politician 'quaffing' wine, or will go 'thrice' to the shop in one day, or say that they 'missed their cell' (lost their mobile phone). 'Did you wish her?' can perhaps be mapped onto British English expressions like 'did you congratulate her?' I wonder if they would say 'Did you send her'  (a birthday card)?

Comment: They won't say `did you send her`, and no Indian I know uses `miss` to mean `lose`.